# Just want to verify about Pax and grsecurity in ubuntu

Tags: kernel, security, patch

I want to know whether latest ubuntu version has Pax and grsecurity patched by default or not.
In other words, if I want to install Pax and grsecurity in ubuntu, do I have to implement manually?
Moreover,is it a good idea to use these in ubuntu?
Is it compatible?